# Access sql for create table with autonumber

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to create a table with a column whose AutoIncrement is Yes.
Here is my query not sure what's wrong in it

```
CREATE TABLE testallcols(SOCycle Text(3),   AutoKey integer AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL, SOData LongBinary   NOT NULL)
```

How do I get my AutoKey column to be an auto increment integer?

Comment: Try removing the Integer part and just use `AutoKey AUTOINCREMENT`.

Comment: May I ask how do I set AllowZeroLength attribute while writing the create table query?

Comment: Access DDL can not set the *AllowZeroLength* attribute directly.  It could be done with check constraint, but it's easier to use the DAO object model to set it.  That could be a useful new question.

Comment: I heard that DAO doesnot work on 64 bit so I am not allowed to go to DAO technology :( Any other alternates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AUTOINCREMENT` and `integer` are two different datatypes as far as Access DDL is concerned.  Use only `AUTOINCREMENT`.  And to make it function correctly as an autonumber, include the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.

This one works without error when tested with ADO/OleDb in Access 2010:

```sql
CREATE TABLE testallcols(SOCycle Text(3), AutoKey AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, SOData LongBinary NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score -1):

CREATE TABLE Tblcontacts
(
contactid AUTOINCREMENT(101,1) PRIMARY KEY ,
firstname CHAR (60),
lastname CHAR (60),
email VARCHAR (75)
);

Comment: How does this any value to the question that the existing accepted answer provides? It's not even for the table the question is for.